# awk to get result of multiple lines in one sentence with if statement

Tags: awk

I am new to `awk` and I was wondering if I could get one single result for an `if` operation on `awk`.

Example:

`cat example.txt`:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

`awk '{ if ($1==0) print "all zeros"; else print "there is 1"}'`

result:

```
all zeros
all zeros
all zeros
all zeros
all zeros
```

I would like to have only one `all zeros` as answer or a `TRUE` . Is this the case where I should use an `awk` function to return something ? Thanks

Comment: does it have to be `awk`? You can use `grep -qvx '0' ip.txt && echo "TRUE"` (or a modified regex depending on the type of input you want to handle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your code in this way. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '$0==0{count++} END{if(count==FNR){print "TRUE"}}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '$0==0{count++} END{if(count==FNR){print "All lines are zeroes"}}' Input_file
```

OR to print a message when some non-zero line(s) found:

```
awk '$0==0{count++} END{if(count==FNR){print "TRUE"} else{print "There is  non-zero line(s) found."}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
$0==0{              ##Checking condition if current line is zero then do following.
  count++           ##Increasing count with 1 here.
}
END{                ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(count==FNR){   ##Checking condition if count is equal to number of total lines of file.
    print "TRUE"    ##If above condition is TRUE then print TRUE here.
  }
}
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `count` is a keyword like `if` ? don't get `count++` is this like `value+=1` in other languages like python ?

Comment: @alex, yes its a variable name, I have added detailed explanation for above too, please do let me know in case of any queries here.

Comment: so I can use `foo` instead of  `count` as well right ? the `++` is the trick to increase every line by 1 if the condition is met correct ?

Comment: @alex, yes that's correct, in `awk` you can directly assign/increment values without defining it too, yes you could give any name which you like too :) cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative using `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='^(0\r?\n)+$' '{print (NF ? "there is 1" : "all zeros")}' file

all zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK` let `file.txt` content be

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

then

```
awk '{nonzero = nonzero || $1!="0"}END{print nonzero?"has not zero":"all zeros"}' file.txt
```

output

```
all zeros
```

Explanation: I am using `nonzero` to store information if some non-zero was already save (value `1`) or not (value `0`). If you are about variable which is not set in `awk` in arithmetic context then its value is `0`, so I do not need to declare `nonzero=0` in `BEGIN` section. I harness `||` which is logical *or* and might be described as follows:

- if you did not see non-zero earlier and do not see it now that mean there is not non-zero element so far (`0 || 0 == 0`)
- if you did not see non-zero earlier and do see it now that mean there is non-zero element so far (`0 || 1 == 1`)
- if you did see non-zero earlier and do not see it now that mean there is non-zero element so far (`1 || 0 == 1`)
- if you did see non-zero eralier and do see it now that mean there is non-zero element so far (`1 || 1 == 1`)

After processing all lines, in `END` section I print either `has not zero` or `all zeros` depending on `nonzero` value and harnessing ternary.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
$ awk '$0{exit v=1}END{printf "All %szeroes\n",(v?"not ":"")}' file
```

Output with sample data:

```
All zeroes
```

Alternative output:

```
All not zeroes
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
$0 {                                       # if record evaluates to non-zero
    exit v=1                               # jump to END with "parameter" 1
}                                          # why continue once non-zero seen
END {
    printf "All %szeroes\n",(v?"not ":"")  # if "parameter" v was set, output "not"
}' file
```

The condition to examine `$0` could of course be something more specific (like `$0=="0"`) but it's sufficient for this purpose. `exit v=1` sets var `v` to value 1 but it also exits the program once a non-zero value of `$0` has been found and jumps to `END` where the value of `v` is examined. The program finally exits with exit code 1. If that is not acceptable, you need to exit from `END` explicitly with `exit 0`.